# HTML Real Time Filter Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I am trying create a real time filter function.

I referenced 
http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/2/
this website to write my function but I find that I can not filter the table.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        var $rows = $("#table tr");
        $("#content").keyup(function() {
            var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
            $rows.show().filter(function() {
                var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
                return !~text.indexOf(val);
            }).hide();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
Filter : <input type="text"id="content"/>
<table id="table">
    <tr><th>No</th><th>Language</th><th>Price</th></tr>
    <tr><td>001</td><td>C#</td><td>7500</td></tr>
    <tr><td>002</td><td>Java</td><td>7000</td></tr>
    <tr><td>003</td><td>C</td><td>6000</td></tr>
    <tr><td>004</td><td>C++</td><td>6500</td></tr>
    <tr><td>005</td><td>PHP</td><td>5000</td></tr>
    <tr><td>006</td><td>jQuery</td><td>9000</td></tr>
    <tr><td>007</td><td>HTML5</td><td>800</td></tr>
    <tr><td>008</td><td>VBasic</td><td>6500</td></tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

For example I type "J" into the textbox then the table will show "java" row and "jQuery" row immediately.

Where is my problem?

Comment: Have you tried moving your JavaScript to the end of the page (just before `</body>` or encompassing it within a `jQuery(function($){ ... }`? Problem is your `$rows` is not able to find the table.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Either move the `script` block to the end of the page (just before the `</body>`) or add them to the `document ready` event, like so:

```
jQuery(function($){
  var $rows = $("#table tr");
  $("#content").keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
      var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
      return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
  });
});
```

See this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/b71oy2ke/1/

The difference between your code and the fiddle you referenced is that the fiddle is including the JavaScript during the `onload` event, whereas your provided source code just includes it unwrapped in the `<head>`.

Answer (score 0):

I actually recently wrote a small jQuery filter function for list items, I have just modified it for use on tables:

```
jQuery.fn.customFilter = function(listObj) {
    var list  = listObj;
    var $input = this;
    var $lis   = $(list).find('tr');
    $input.on('input', function() {
      var term = $input.val().toLowerCase();
      $.each($lis, function() {
        isContains = $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1;
        if( isContains ) {
          $(this).show();
        } else {
          $(this).hide();
        }
      });
    });
    return this;
}
```

Example Usage:

```
$('#content').customFilter('#table');
```

Here is your [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/3707/)